# R - Assign uniroot answer to namespace

Tags: r

I've used used uniroot to find the value of an unknown in a function.

```
$root
[1] 0.9613575 # This is the value that I am looking to use later

$f.root
[1] -0.0001972946

$iter
[1] 12

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

Is there a way to assign the $root answer to a variable so that I can call it later without doing it by inspection?

Comment: do you mean `myVal <- uniroot(....)$root`?

Comment: Would that not equate all of the output to myval? Is there a way to assign 0.9613575 to myval without doing it manually?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without doing it manually," but this is the most direct method to assign the value  0.9613575 to the variable name myVal.

Comment: @jpyth32 No it wouldn't equate all the output.  The `$root` portion of that code extracts the value stored in 'root' so that's the only part getting assigned to `myval`.